# How can 1X1 Conv act as a fully connected layer?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

While reviewing papers and code on GitHub, I’ve frequently noticed the use of convolutional layers in place of linear layers. And I’ve learned that a 1x1 convolutional layer calculates the embedding feature on the channel dimension, functioning somewhat like a linear layer. However, I’m still somewhat unclear about how it actually works.

```
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn

    fc_standard = nn.linear(64, 32)
    fc_conv2d = nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
    fc_conv1d = nn.Conv1d(64, 32, kernel_size=1, stride=1)

    # Input
    x = torch.randn(256, 1, 64, 64)  # (Batches, Channels, Lengths, Emb_sizes).
    
    # standard fc
    x = fc_standard(x)   # output(256, 1, 64, 32)
    
    # conv2d
    x = x.view(-1, 64, 1, 1)
    x = fc_conv2d(x)
    x = x.view(256, 1, -1, 32)   # output(256, 1, 64, 32)

    # conv1d
    x = x.view(256, 64, 64).transpose(1, 2)
    x = fc_conv1d(x) # output(256, 32, 64)
    x = x.transpose(1,2).unsqueeze(1)   # output(256, 1, 64, 32)
```

I attempted to substitute the fully connected layer with a 1x1 convolution as mentioned above. The results I obtained using the conv2d method were similar to the standard fully connected layer in my network. Are these three implementations equivalent? Can these two types of convolution actually function as a linear layer?

Comment: So consider that as the kernel size increases for a conv layer, you begin to approach the same behavior as a fully connected linear layer. As intuition for the 1x1 kernel approach, you could consider that neither of these approaches contain information about the local area around the pixel, same as a fully connected linear layer. (also just a heads up your example isn't functioning)

Comment: Also the first two parameters for conv are channels in and channels out. In Torch, shapes of images are specified by standard as batch x channels x height x width